# Vector of void function pointers with parameters C++

Tags: c++

I'm creating an application with a class that has a number of animation methods. I need these animation methods to be called in a random way. So, my idea was to create a vector of void function pointers, and iterate through the vector. I can't get it to compile though. I'm getting the error: `"invalid use of void expression"`.

Applicable code:

.h

```
std::vector<void(*)(int,float)> animationsVector;
void setAnimations();
void circleAnimation01(int circleGroup, float time);
```

.cpp

```
polygonCluster01::polygonCluster01()
{
    setAnimations();
}

void polygonCluster01::setAnimations()
{
    animationsVector.push_back(circleAnimation01(1,2.0)); //error is here
}

void polygonCluster01::circleAnimation01(int circleGroup, float animLength)
{
    //other code
}
```

I've followed some other posts here which suggest I'm doing it right, but it still won't compile, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your `push_pack` parameter is a function call, not a function pointer. Function pointers do not have parameters with them. You would need to store the function pointer *plus* the parameters separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`polygonCluster01::circleAnimation01` is not a free-standing function, but a member function. Thus, you need a *member function pointer* to store its adress. Here is the type you're looking for :

```
std::vector<void(polygonCluster01::*)(int,float)> animationsVector;
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Edit:** let's complete this answer.

When you give the correct type to your vector, it still won't compile. This is because, as stated by crashmstr, function pointers and member function pointers are just that - a pointer to a (member) function. In particular, they can't store parameters for later use, which you are trying to do.

So what you actually need is not a mere (member) function pointer, but something that can wrap a function and some parameters to call it later.

Well, C++11 has you covered ! Take a look at [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). It's a type-erased container, designed to do just what is written above. You can use it like this :

```
std::vector<std::function<void(polygonCluster01*)>> animationsVector;

...

animationsVector.push_back(std::bind(
    &polygonCluster01::circleAnimation01, // Grab the member function pointer
    std::placeholders::_1, // Don't give a caller for now
    1, 2.0 // Here are the arguments for the later call
));

...

animationsVector[0](this); // Call the function upon ourselves
```

Comment: yeah, but what about problem with push_back?

Answer (score 0):

Your vector contains function pointers, not the result of the function you are calling in there.

`animationsVector.push_back(circleAnimation01(1,2.0));`

Use this instead

`animationsVector.push_back(circleAnimation01);`

The `invalid use of void expression` that you are getting is because you are trying to store the result of the `circleAnimation01` function call which is `void` instead of a pointer to a function that returns void upon receiving an int and a float.

Also, as Quentin has stated, you need them to be functions, not member functions, either change the signature of the vector or change those members to free functions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that error makes a lot of sense now.